# Error - Eclipse client trying to reconnect to TFS - "LocationWebService"

Tags: eclipse, tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

When eclipse tries to reconnect to TFS (username.visualstudio.com) the 'authentication window' is replaced by a window that seems to describe available services and the authentication process stops here.

[image]

The content of this window is as follows:

```
LocationWebService
The following operations are supported. For a formal definition, please review the Service Description.

ConfigureAccessMapping 
Connect 
QueryServices 
RemoveAccessMapping 
RemoveServiceDefinitions 
SaveServiceDefinitions 
SetDefaultAccessMapping
```

With VS2010 I can still connect to TFS without problems.
Also, both with eclipse and VS2010 I can connect to codeplex (tfs).

Clearing cookies and/or cache from IE or Chrome doesn't help.
Everything is fresh installed, so I assume it's up to date.

How can I resolve this issue with Eclipse - TFS - username.visualstudio.com?

Answer (score 1):

I had to reinstall the 2013 version (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40785) and everything started working. It's either a bug in an older version or mismatch with the server version being connected to.

Comment: That's correct; Visual Studio Online has changes that require the latest plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue too. It only happens when I try to connect myuser.visualstudio.com, with my domain TFS it can authenticate without any problem.

I see that you are running Windows 7, in my case the eclipse TFS stop working with Windows 8.

Comment: Yes, I can connect to codeplex without any problems at all - it only happens with myuser.visualstudio.com